# How to add SqlDependency for AngularJs with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, entity-framework

I'm creating a database notification web application with Angular, ASP.NET MVC 5 and Entity Framework. Since I don't have much knowledge I'm referring to the following article so I'm asking if some one can help bellow tutorial with Entity Framework will be very much appreciated.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/806919/SignalR-with-ASP-NET-MVC

Answer (score 0):

Actually AngularJS is used in front end. This dependency should be included on backend. To add EF to your project, just run the following command in Visual Studio:

under menu Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console

```
Install-Package EntityFramework
```

Comment: no no, i can install EF but i want to know how to add SqlDependancy to EF because above example have used ADO.NET